# wordpress site is not opening any page. showing error that this page has redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am working on a membership site. The users who didn't select any level and have registered their date of birth, I want to redirect them to membership level when they try to visit any page. I am using wordpress and buddypress is installed.  I have written this code in function.php.

```
add_action('init','redirect_to_levels');
function redirect_to_levels(){
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $Birthday =  xprofile_get_field_data( 'Birthday', $user_ID );
    $did_level = displayed_user_on_level($user_ID); //this returns the  level
    $redirect_page = get_permalink(215);

    if(!$did_level && $Birthday ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect_page ); exit;    
    }
}
```

but problem is that when I try to visit the site, browser doesn't open any page and shows this error.
"This webpage has a redirect loop"
and when I remove the wp_redirect, it works fine.

Comment: if you echo the `$redirect_page` do you get the right value?

Comment: yes, I get the right value

Comment: but I just found that is_page() doesn't work in functions.php. Is there any other way to find the current page.?

Answer (score 0):

When in redirects to the $redirect_page, that page also runs the redirect_to_levels function and redirects it to itself again which causes a redirect loop.

You can add

```
if ( is_page(215) )
exit;
```

to the first line of the function.

Comment: I just found that is_page() doesn't work in functions.php. Is there any other way to find the current page.? thanks

Comment: have done it. I also saw lot of threads about is_page() function that it doesn't work in function.php. So what I did is I used php function to find the current page url which is $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; then compared the redirect url with $actual_link and got the required answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also not sure about this. but what I think is ,

functions on functions.php are running every page loads. so when you load a page it is rederecting. so it's hapening again and again.

add this code a custom page template.( to the page that you checking user levels )

or get your user level checking page id and do the following. (lets think your id is 123)

```
<?php if(is_page(123)) { ?> 
  add_action('init','redirect_to_levels');
<?php } ?>
```

tell me if this is working. I didn't check this code. try this on a test site.

Comment: not working. Now the whole code now works because it is outside the add_action hook.

Comment: so cant you add it to a custom page template ? do not write your redirect_to_levels() function in that page. just add   

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $Birthday =  xprofile_get_field_data( 'Birthday', $user_ID );
    $did_level = displayed_user_on_level($user_ID); //this returns the  level
    $redirect_page = get_permalink(215);

    if(!$did_level && $Birthday ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect_page ); exit;    
    }


before the get header function